# How to properly add Digital Asset Link for Android Deep Link

Tags: android-studio, android-deep-link

I am trying to add a deep link to my Android app. I have followed Google documentation to generate a Digital Asset Link json file with the sha1 finger print for both my released and debug;

Here is the file

```
    [
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.packagename.appname",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
        ["34:95:CF:41:BD:54:29:05:4F:B5:44:85:04:75:74:E2:01:72:DF:V9:C9:36:8C:17:E0:3C:28:E5:3B:48:58:77"]
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.packagename.appname",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
        ["89:2C:23:51:A1:C7:8A:AF:34:1F:1F:2A:94:A6:1A:28:42:2C:21:19:15:9E:7F:B6:DE:03:BC:B9:AD:1C:1B:65"]
    }
  },
```

I have published this file to Github pages, like so https://domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json

I have updated my Intentfilters like so

```
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="prontoinvoice.co"
                android:pathPrefix="/return" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="prontoinvoice.co"
                android:pathPrefix="/reauth" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I am wondering what I am missing, I even pushed the JSOn file to firebase hosting, and still the same result. I get error 1024 when I trying.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mal-formed JSON that consumed my whole day. I needed to add a separate signature for both debug and release key so I copied and pasted and in the process the assetlinks.json file was not formatted correctly.

For anyone caught in this loop, please validate your JSON with any online JSON validator tool.